# How to establish an OLE DB Destination in SSIS in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, authentication, ssis, dataflowtask

I am trying to make a data flow task in SSIS where I insert data from an OLE DB Source to an OLE DB Destination (i.e. two different SQL Server instances on different VMs). I was able to get the OLE DB Source connection to work. The OLE DB Source is a SQL Server instance on a personal VM that I use for staging and data conversion.

However, when I try to establish the OLE DB Destination I keep getting an error because the destination SQL Server is on a different VM/data server. No matter which provider, server name, or credentials I use I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone please point me the in the right direction?

[image]

I usually use "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" for the source so I thought I could do the same with the destination, but I'm not sure which authentication I should be using?

[image]

Here is the error I get when I try, for example, the sa account:

[image]

Comment: Either the connection string is incorrect or you do not have the correct permissions, or firewall settings may not be open from one VM to the other.

Comment: I can reproduce your error by using an obviously bad name and password https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKMA1.png so I would confirm you have the correct credentials for the sa account on the other server.  `sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 1secret! -Q "SELECT @@servername"` Try that against your current instance as well as the one that is not responding. If you manage to connect correctly, then it'd seem you know your passwords and there's an issue elsewhere in the SSIS connection manager but password smells the most probable

Comment: are you using fully qualified URIs for your server names?